# Letting $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ be families of cardinal numbers $a_i < b_i$, prove there is an injection between $\sum_{i}a_i$ to $\prod_i b_i$

Tags: set-theory

Letting $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ be families of cardinal numbers $a_i < b_i$, prove there is an injection between $\sum_{i}a_i$ to $\prod_i b_i$.

I need it to complete the solution to [Halmos' Naive Set Theory Cardinal Arithmetic Exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173311/halmos-naive-set-theory-cardinal-arithmetic-exercise).

Comment: This is called [Koenig's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245193/cardinality-of-the-union-is-less-than-the-cardinality-of-the-cartesian-product?rq=1 the comment by Asaf contains the answer.